# Why is this the cost of this PHP function so different between versions?

Tags: php

Why is the execution time of this Function so different between versions?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/930e9dfad62620d569652c6a4b747bba9b4e1d7b

For example

PHP 5.4.10 it takes 0.0004429817199707

PHP 5.3.10 it takes 4.7922134399414E-5

PHP 7.1.0 it takes 3.4809112548828E-5

Why is there such a huge difference and what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I wasn't able to reliably reproduce those results. Try clicking "execute" a few times -- the timing jumps around quite a bit.

Comment: It is just fake. When i checked 5.4.10 then it is showing `5.2928924560547E-5`

Comment: It also gives different variations by executing the same code with the same version. May be its depend on server's handling capacity with other request, not sure....

Comment: For reliable results you should run the code in a loop 1000 times or more and compute the average duration. As it is now it produces different results on each run because of server load.

Comment: For me It shows times in order of `e^-6` which means 0.00000050 (a very small number / time). I think you forgot the significance of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot about E-5 at the end :) This way

PHP 5.4.10 it takes 0.0004429817199707 =~  0.000442981719

PHP 5.3.10 it takes 4.7922134399414E-5 =~  0.00004792213

PHP 7.1.0 it takes 3.4809112548828E-5 =~ 0.00003480911

Keep in mind, that with so small values probably more influence on results has server load in that moment and other things not related to your code. To have better results, you should run your code in loop (ie. milion times).

Here's modified version of your code (just added loop around measured code)

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96a66221b2e6605ffc8c5dee58ee1ae06f47ae4a